# MATLAB Script to Run Formula with Multiple Variables

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot 
$$p(n)=1-\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\frac{365!n!}{i!(365-n+i)!2^{i}(n-2i)!365^{n}}$$
over various positive integer values of $n$ in MATLAB, but it obviously has very large numbers in it deriving from the factorials leading me to rearrange it as
$$1-\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\prod_{j=366-n+i}^{365} \,j \,\prod_{t=n-2i+1}^{n}t\,\frac{1}{i!2^{i}365^{n}} \enspace,$$
which is leading me to get numbers rather than just inf.  My current script is below, but it currently still isn't giving me a correct plot. Is my rearrangement incorrect or is the code wrong and if so how do I fix it?

```
for n=1:100;
    i=0:floor(n/2);
    j=(366-n+i):365;
    t=(n-2.*i+1):n;
    tosum=prod(j) * prod(t) * (1)./(factorial(i) .* (2.^i) .* (365^n));
    p(n)=1-sum(tosum);
end
n=1:100;
plot(n,p)
```

Comment: $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is obtained wit h`\lfloor n/2 \rfloor`.  Could you proofread the line that assigns to `tosum`?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi thanks, I edited in the floor symbol and went back through the tosum line and added some spacing to ensure everything was shown properly.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the first line is unnecessary, but more importantly, what do you expect the third line to do?  Note that `i` is a row vector, and the range (colon) operator expects scalar arguments.